# On maximum principle for parabolic equations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

> Let $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ compact with no boundary and assume that
>
> $\begin{align} \partial_t u-\Delta u&>0 \quad \text{in}
>  \;M\times(0,T]\\u(\cdot,0) &\geq 0\quad \text{in} \;M \end{align}$

In my opinion, a weak maximum principle implies that $u \geq 0\;.$ However, my professor claims that we deduce a strictly positive $u$ using the strong maximum principle. Why is this true? I can't see why the strong maximum principle could be applied here in any case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that $u$ is strictly positive for $t>0$? Otherwise, if the initial condition is zero somewhere then obviously $u$ attains zero at $t=0$. Or do you assume $u_0 >0$?

Comment: @SC2020 Yes, the claim is that $u>0$ for $t>0$... The initial data $u_0$ are not assumed strictly positive. Although it seems a simple argument, I'm highly confused.

Comment: Do you have additional conditions for the boundary $\partial M \times(0,T]$? Suppose $u\geq0$ on the parabolic boundary. Assume $u(x,t)=0$ somewhere for some $(x,t)\in M\times(0,T]$, then you can deduce from the strong maximum principle that $u$ is constant up until time $t>0$. But if $u$ is constant in some region then $u_t-\Delta u=0$ in that region. Contradiction. Maybe this helps.